# Few warnings [expects parameter]

Tags: mysql

I've been trying to display the number of rows using this code but it keep says

1 Rows which is wrong

```
<?php

            $link = mysql_connect("localhost", "gamin1_forum", "password123");
            mysql_select_db("gamin1_forumdb", $link);

            $result = mysql_query("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM smf_personal_messages", $link);
            $num_rows = mysql_num_rows($result);

            echo "$num_rows Rows";

            ?>
```

Rows are approximately 1443 but it kept saying 1

Comment: The mysql_* extension is deprecated, [don't get started with it](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12859942/why-shouldnt-i-use-mysql-functions-in-php)

Answer (score 0):

This is true, `mysql_num_rows()` is telling that there was one "row" returned. You need to check the value of the returned row to get your count. Try this

```
$link = mysql_connect("localhost", "gamin1_forum", "password123");
$result = mysql_query("SELECT COUNT(*) as cnt FROM smf_personal_messages", $link);
$row = mysql_fetch_array($result);

echo ($row['cnt']);
```

On a side note, you should not use mysql_* functions for security reasons. Try PDO/mysqli_* functions

Answer (score 0):

The `Count(*)` returns you one row which contains the number of rows as a value.

By using `mysql_num_rows($result)` you are actually counting the amount of rows of the `Count(*)` result **which really is one**.

Change it to:

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM smf_personal_messages", $link);
$num_rows = mysql_num_rows($result);
```

Or just use the `Count(*)` value (which is probably better since it count in the DB and not retrieving the whole table for it) using `mysql_fetch_array`.