# expects parameter warning 1 to be resource

Tags: php

This below code is giving me `mysql_fetch_array()` expects parameter

```
<?php
    $query = $forumdb->prepare("SELECT COUNT(*) as cnt FROM smf_personal_messages");
    $query->execute();
    $num_rows = mysql_fetch_array($query);

    if ($query->rowCount() == 0) {
        echo "<tr><td colspan='6'><small>No rows found</small></td></tr>";
    }

    echo ($num_rows['cnt']);
?>
```

> Warning: mysql_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be resource,
>   object given in /home/gamin1/public_html/ucp/forumstats.php on line
>   127

Comment: What database interface are you using? Because you can't play pick-a-mix with MySQL, MySQLi and PDO

Comment: "pick-a-mix", I like that. [Is that for here or to go?](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7fHj_YWsI-I&t=0m15s) :-)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12859942/why-shouldnt-i-use-mysql-functions-in-php

Answer (score 1):

Seems to be a reasonable assumption that you want to use [PDO](http://docs.php.net/pdo). As has already been mentioned, you can't mix [pdo(_msyql)](http://docs.php.net/manual/en/ref.pdo-mysql.php) with the [other mysql apis](http://docs.php.net/manual/en/mysqlinfo.api.choosing.php).
But there are some other issues with your script:

```
<?php
// not an error per se, but:
// no placeholders in the query + sent only once -> prepared statement superfluous
$result = $forumdb->query("SELECT COUNT(*) as cnt FROM smf_personal_messages");
// assuming PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE=>PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION, so no error handling here....

// Count(*) with no explicit grouping always returns exactly one record, so
// ->rowCount() will do you no good
// instead fetch that one record and read the field holding the value of Count(*) as cnt
$row = $result->fetch();
if ( 0==$row['cnt'] ) {
    echo "<tr><td colspan='6'><small>table cotains no records</small></td></tr>";
}
else {
    echo '# of rows: ', row['cnt'];
}
```

Comment: OP reposted http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32668158/query-fetching-issue and used one of the answers in their new code. I voted to close the other one as unclear, since we have no idea which MySQL API they're using to connect with. Edit: My guess http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32666137/few-warnings-expects-parameter they're still using mysql_ to connect with.

Comment: Exactly. I think/feel the OP needs a good jolt with tutorials. They're not far off though ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Use `$query->fetch()` instead of `mysql_fetch_array($query)`.

You are using PDO here: http://php.net/manual/fr/pdostatement.fetch.php