# Query fetching issue

Tags: php

The below code is meant to be shown the total number of members but it doesn't show nothing

```
<?php
            $query = $forumdb->prepare("SELECT totalMembers FROM smf_settings");
            $query->execute();
            $num_rows = $query->fetch();
            ?>
            <div class="media-body">
            <p id="greet" align="left">Total Members: <?php echo .$num_rows['totalMembers']. ?> <p>
            </div>
```

Comment: @SubinThomas `$num_rows` is just a variable calling the `fetch()` function. `$num_rows` does not mean `num_rows()`.

Comment: Seeing your other questions, and using `mysql_` functions, is really hard to say which MySQL API you're using to connect with. Voted to close as unclear.

Comment: My bad.. Thanks.. @Fred-ii-

Comment: possible exact duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32667030/expects-parameter-warning-1-to-be-resource

Comment: I'm using PDO @Fred-ii-

Comment: you need to post your full code. Check for errors http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.error-handling.php --- http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php or see the answer given below.

Comment: you also shouldn't be reposting the same question. I don't mean to sound "mean" here, but you would benefit more from reading the right tutorials. Your questions have been one after another using different MySQL APIs/functions and hoping something will eventually work.

Comment: its been awhile i'm behind this honestly, nothing worked so far. But one thing i noticed is, the output shows 1 even tho it is not. That was the same problem in the previous question i asked http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32666137/few-warnings-expects-parameter, i followed it and worked but this one is really driving me crazy

Comment: Here, the answer to all your problems http://www.mysqltutorial.org/php-querying-data-from-mysql-table/ - Follow that to a **"T".** - Including any links in there. This comment should be converted to an answer ;-)

Answer (score 1):

To count total number of members you can use `count`

```
$query->execute();
$rows = $query->fetch();
$num_rows = count($rows);
```

OR change your query to `count` and use `fetchColumn`

```
$query = $forumdb->prepare("SELECT COUNT(totalMembers) FROM smf_settings");
$query->execute();
/* Check the number of rows that match the SELECT statement */
$num_rows=$res->fetchColumn();
```

Comment: For most databases,  PDOStatement::rowCount() does not return the number of rows affected by a SELECT statement. 
Instead, use  PDO::query() to issue a SELECT COUNT(*) statement with the same predicates as your intended SELECT statement, then use  PDOStatement::fetchColumn() to retrieve the number of rows that will be returned. 
Your application can then perform the correct action.

Comment: You are right @SubinThomas thanks for updating my knowledge

Comment: What do you mean by does't work??Have your get and error and it is better for you to post your full code

Comment: `<?php
    $query = $forumdb->prepare("SELECT totalMembers FROM smf_settings");
                                $query->execute();
                                $rows = $query->fetch();
                                $num_rows = count($rows);

   
    ?>
    <div class="media-body">
                <p id="greet" align="left">Total Members: <?php echo $num_rows['totalMembers'] ?> <p>
    </div>`

Comment: @Saty Unclear questions always take 10 times as long than... well, you know ;-)